# Delay to see grant command result in 'show grants'

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I noticed that when I run "grant select on table <> to role <>" it takes some time to see it in "show grants" command.
Is it normal ?
Why is there such delay ?

Thanks

Comment: Ideally, this should not be happening. I tested it on my environment and confirmed the show grants operation lists the change immediately.